# Does MongoDB's Map/Reduce always return results in floats?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am using Mongoid, which is on top of the Ruby MongDB driver.  Even though my Map's emit is giving out a `parseInt(num)`, and the Reduce's return is giving back also a `parseInt(num)`, the final results still are floats.

Is that particular to MongoDB?  Any way to make it integer instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function officially takes a string as parameter. This string is parsed as if it were an integer, thus ignoring everything after the first non-numeric character. If you provide a floating point number, it will be converted to a string before it is parsed.

The `parseInt` functions returns a [`Number`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp), not an integer. `Number` is the **only numeric data type** in JavaScript; there is no distinction between integers and floats.

So while `parseInt` will remove any decimals, the data type doesn't change. Therefore Mongoid doesn't know whether to treat the result as a float or an integer. You're responsible for converting the result to an integer, as you can see in [this example](http://willj.net/2010/07/12/map-reduce-using-mongoid/).

#### Update

I came across the [`NumberLong`](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-776) type, which represents a 64-bit integer. If you return `new NumberLong(num)` from your reduce function, Mongoid may treat it as an integer type.

Note that you'll need MongoDB 1.6 for this to work in the MongoDB Shell. I don't know whether Mongoid supports it yet.

Comment: so in MongoDB Shell or in Firefox, if it is `parseInt('1') + parseInt('123')`, then `124` is returned, not 124.0.  Where in MongoDB is it triggered to have `.0` added to the end?  I can even make it so by `123 * 1.0` or `123 + 1.0`

Comment: @Jian Lin: MongoDB doesn't 'add' `.0`, but Mongoid represents it that way. Mongoid only knows that it's a `Number`, but it can't tell whether it's an integer or float. See my updated answer for a possible alternative.